# сохранение активности радиокнопки в form после валидации в php

Tags: php, html

Есть форма и в ней:

```
<td>Моб.корона <input type="radio" name="place" value="Моб.корона"/></td>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить активность радиокнопки после *PHP* проверки формы.

Т.е. если есть ошибка проверки, идет возврат к форме.

В `input` переменные сохраняю  через сессию `value ="<? echo $_SESSION[''] ?>"`, активность радиокнопки исчезает!?

Answer (score 1):

После обновления страницы надо "вручную" поставить свойство "checked" у радиокнопки. Как то так

```
<input type="radio" name="place" value="Моб.корона" <?php if ($_SESSION['place'] == 'Моб.корона'){echo ' checked';}?>/>
```

Comment: благодарю, Иван! Все заработало! не понял что значит "вручную"!?

Comment: "вручную" - то что код PHP пришлось для этого добавлять

Comment: Понял...добавил. Тогда еще один вопрос для новичка:

Comment: для меня имеется в виду)))) У меня в форме 26 данных в разных полях  и кнопках! Есть ли способ чтоб после проверки в случае ошибки не прописывать в каждом value отдельно переменную $_SESSION[''], а чтоб нужная переменная по name из массива $_SESSION в нужное поле попадала.

Comment: Можно написать функции, которые будут подставлять значения в поля, что-нибудь вроде `<?=value('field_name', 'default_value')?>` `<?=checked('field_name', 'default_value')?>` и т.д. и всю логику хранения и подстановки данных спрятать в эти функции

Comment: понял...попробую...хотя никогда еще подобное не делал...благодарю Иван